# I am receiving junk on the serial port

Tags: c, windows, serial-port

I have an Atmel mirocontroller sending data which I want to receive on my PC over COM1.

When I attach a terminal program, the data is received correctly (it is all ascii, all printable except for \n).

However, my code appears to be receiving junk (non-ascii chars). Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? Thanks

Sending code, just for info

```
// USART options.
static const usart_options_t USART_CONSOLE_OPTIONS =
{
    .baudrate     = 115200,
    .charlength   = 8,
    .paritytype   = USART_NO_PARITY,
    .stopbits     = USART_1_STOPBIT,
    .channelmode  = USART_NORMAL_CHMODE
};
```

Receiving code

```
E_boolean OpenCom1(void)
{
   COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts;

   comPortHandle = CreateFile("COM1",  // Specify port device: default "COM1"
   GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,       // Specify mode that open device.
   0,                                  // the device isn't shared.
   NULL,                               // the object gets a default security.
   OPEN_EXISTING,                      // Specify which action to take on file.
   0,                                  // default (not overlapped i/o).
   NULL);                              // default (hTemplate must be NULL for COM devices).

   if (comPortHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
      return False;

   deviceControlBlock.DCBlength = sizeof(deviceControlBlock);

    if((GetCommState(comPortHandle, &deviceControlBlock) == 0))
    {
      // CodeMe: do what?
      return False;
    }

    deviceControlBlock.BaudRate = CBR_115200;
    deviceControlBlock.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
    deviceControlBlock.Parity   = NOPARITY;
    deviceControlBlock.ByteSize = DATABITS_8;
    deviceControlBlock.fRtsControl = 0;

    if (!SetCommState(comPortHandle, &deviceControlBlock))
    {
      // CodeMe: do what?
      return False;
    }

    // set short timeouts on the comm port.
    timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = MAXDWORD;
    timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = MAXDWORD;
    timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 1000;   // oen second
    timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 1;
    timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 1;
    if (!SetCommTimeouts(comPortHandle, &timeouts))
    {
      // CodeMe: do what?
      return False;
    }

   FlushFileBuffers(comPortHandle);

   PurgeComm (comPortHandle, PURGE_TXABORT | PURGE_RXABORT | PURGE_TXCLEAR | PURGE_RXCLEAR);

   return True;
}//OpenCom1()

// +=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=
void      ReadCharacterFromCom1(INPUT char *theCharacter)
{
   DWORD numBytesRead;

   numBytesRead = 0;

   while (numBytesRead == 0)
   {
      ReadFile(comPortHandle,           // handle of file to read
               theCharacter,            // store read data here
               sizeof(char),            // number of bytes to read
               &numBytesRead,           // pointer to number of bytes actually read
               NULL);
   }

   return;
}//ReadCharacterFromCom1()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "junk"?  How do you know the "junk" is not due to electrical noise?

Comment: @HotLicks +1  I mean non-ascii chars and since a terminal program  receives correctly I am inclined to blame my own code.

Comment: Did you try printing the hexadecimal value of each byte received through `theCharacter` ?

Comment: Before you assume you are "receiving" junk, initialize the receiving buffer with a non-ASCII value such as 0xff.  On return from the `ReadFile` call, check the error return call and the number of bytes actually read.  Since the terminal emulator program shows the data is being sent OK, incorrect use of the receive buffer (when there is no data) is usually the bug.  Try reading a whole line or a buffer's worth of data at a time, instead of just one byte per system call.  BTW if the data is plain ASCII, then you only need 7 data bits and should use parity.

Comment: To isolate your pc code contact pin 2 and 3 together on your 9 pin serial cable. Then in your software send a string, it should be echoed back via the bridged 2 and 3. When that works, check that the UART dividers on your Atmel are set up properly. The best way is to have your board send 'U' repeatedly. You should see a baud rate of exactly 115200. Now connect the two.

Comment: Post the code that calls your `ReadCharacterFromCom1` .Maybe you just have an error in the formatting when you print out the received character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function "ReadFile" is called with a "sizeof(char)" for number of bytes to read. This will alway be evaluated to be 1, probably not the value that you intended. The result is every call to the ReadCharacterFromCom1 will only read 1 valid character from the port and return, the rest that you saw are the junks left in the buffer because the buffer is not (manually) terminated with a null.

Suggest that you change it to:

```
 /* ============================================================ */
DWORD ReadCharacterFromCom1(char *pszBuffer, int nMaxCharToRead)
{
    DWORD dwBytesRead = 0;
    while (dwBytesRead == 0)
    {   ReadFile(comPortHandle, // handle of file to read
            pszBuffer,  // store read data here
            nMaxCharToRead, // number of bytes to read
            &dwBytesRead,   // pointer to number of bytes actually read
            NULL);
    }
    // terminate string with null
    pszBuffer[dwBytesRead] = 0;
    return dwBytesRead;
}

// test code ------------------------
char szBuffer[512];
DWORD dwCount = ReadCharacterFromCom1(szBuffer, sizeof(szBuffer)-1);
printf(_T("Receive %d chars: <%s>"), nCount, szBuffer);
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming baud rate, number of data bits, parity and the number of stop bits are set up correctly you most likley are missing to set up any kind of flow control. You do not show us (fully) how you initialise the DCB.

Flow control inhibits buffer overflows in the sender/receiver.

Depending on what kind of serial cabeling you use and what kind of data shall be transferred soft- or hardware flow control can be used.

Hardware flow control is the preferred kind of flow control as it works for plain ASCII **and** binary data to be transferred. Its requiers a fully wired serial connection. It is also referred to as RTS and/or DTR flow control.

If you only have the mininal three-wire RS232/V.24 cabeling you might like to use software flow control (also referrred to as Xon/Xoff handshake). Xon/Xoff-handshake flow control works for ASCII data to be transfered only. To send binary data via such a connection it needs to be encode to pure ASCII. Use base64 encoding for example to do so.

How to set up flow control under windows you might like to read here: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/89698/

This http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff802693.aspx might serve as a reference.

Comment: Bad flow control would not cause garbage to show up on the screen, but having the wrong baud rate would. it would be better that he just tried sending single characters with a giant pause between them, that would isolate out the potential flow control problem, and the only thing that could that be left is a baud rate problem, or a problem with how he passes his pointers around in the code.

Comment: @c.fogelklou: My answer implied the four basic parameters had been setup correctly. But you are right, this does not necessarily need to be the case. I updated my answer accordingly.